# How to find nth prime palindrome in Go

Tags: go

I am kinda new in Go, I tried to find nth prime palindrome numbers but it always return 0, what did I do wrong here, output from my code should be 131.

For the sake of clearance, below I'll give sample of n and its return.

n: 1, Output: 2

n: 2, Output: 3

n: 3, Output: 5

n: 5, Output: 11

n: 6, Output: 101

n: 7, Output: 111

n: 8, Output: 151

```
n := 7

counter := 0

currNum := 1

palindromeNumber := 0

for counter < int(n) {
    currNum++
    isPrime := false
    for i := 2; i <= int(math.Sqrt(float64(currNum))); i++ {
        if currNum%i == 0 {
            isPrime = true

            var number, remainder, temp int

            var reverse int = 0

            temp = currNum

            // For Loop used in format of While Loop
            for {
                remainder = number % 10
                reverse = reverse*10 + remainder
                number /= 10
                if number == 0 {
                    // Break Statement used to exit from loop
                    break
                }
            }

            if temp == reverse {
                palindromeNumber = reverse
            }

            break
        }
    }
    if !isPrime {
        counter++
    }
}

return int64(palindromeNumber)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prime numbers are numbers that have only 2 factors: 1 and themselves, that means if a number `n` is a prime number, it won't be divisible by any numbers in range from `2` to `sqrt(n)`. But in your code, I see

```
if currNum%i == 0 {
        isPrime = true
        ...
}
```

Why is `currNum` prime if it's divisible by `i` with i in range from `2` to `sqrt(n)` ? It's wrong. If `currNum` meets this condition, it have to be a non-prime number.
Moreover, I don't see the assignment for `var number`, so it will be its zero value `0` that also make `palindromeNumber = 0`.

I think you should keep the prime check and the palindrome check in two separate functions to avoid confusions in your code (such as `func isPrime` and `func isPalindrome`).

Comment: Even if I split the code. it doesnt really works

Comment: Because logics of the algorithm in your code are not correct. See prime check algorithm here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/write-a-golang-program-to-check-whether-a-given-number-is-prime-number-or-not

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is the variable **number**. You create it and maybe you wanted to copy currNum into number before using number to calculate the reverted, but you are not doing that.

Comment: if I assign number with currNum it shows a wrong return, ex: when n = 3, the output is 4

Comment: There are more problems. But you are using number to calculate something, but you just created number and it have nothing.

Comment: Every time you do this: if currNum%i == 0, you consider the number prime. I recomend you divide logic in steps. Do the whole calculation to check if the number is prime, end after that, you check if the number is palindrome.